# How Alias increase performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am studying a Select code in SQL server and I am having difficult to understand why we have to use alias in this Where condition here:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
                    (SELECT 1
                        FROM ComprasPedidosItens CPI WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE CPI.NumeroMiro IS NOT NULL AND  CPI.CodigoPedido = ComprasPedidos.CodigoPedido)
                    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Because your query (which you only partially copied so it's hard to tell) probably references the table elsewhere more than one time. So you need the Alias so SQL knows which one.

Comment: You've posted only a part of the query, it's kinda hard to answer like this.

Comment: in the sub-query there is a column `CodigoPedido` that exists in both `ComprasPedidosItens` and `ComprasPedidos`. The alias is required to identify the column is from which table. But `alias` does not improve the performance

Comment: In query optimization, `Alias` will not help at all. It is just to use to identify `columns` from where it comes (i.e. `table`).

Comment: Also, use of (NOLOCK) everywhere for minor performance gains is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @JacobH - It is possible to tell from the fragment posted that the alias is not required. Regardess of what columns or tables may exist in outer scopes they won't change the semantics of that fragment

Answer (score 0):

For my knowledge, Alias does not have any effect on the performance of the query execution. But if the alias is used in the select list, there might be chances of reducing the performance based on the query.

Answer (score 0):

An alias doesn't increase performance. However, it helps making he difference when the same table is used twice (or more) in a query (with subquery, join, and so on...)

In example, let's consider this table, having a foreign key referencing the same table :

MyTable :

```
Self-reference
 +--------+
 |        |
 v        |
id | MyTable_id | data
```

And this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN MyTable
ON MyTable.id = MyTable.MyTable_id
--     ^           ^
--     |           |
-- Which table ? Which table ?
-- The first ?   The first ?
--     Or           Or
-- the second ? the second ?
```

Using Aliases, it makes sense

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
LEFT JOIN MyTable T2
ON T1.id = T2.MyTable_id
-- Now we know.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the `CPI` alias then it is *not* required.

```
NOT EXISTS (
            (SELECT 1
                FROM ComprasPedidosItens CPI WITH (NOLOCK)
                WHERE CPI.NumeroMiro IS NOT NULL AND  CPI.CodigoPedido = ComprasPedidos.CodigoPedido)
            )
```

Is the same as

```
NOT EXISTS (
            (SELECT 1
                FROM ComprasPedidosItens WITH (NOLOCK)
                WHERE NumeroMiro IS NOT NULL AND  CodigoPedido = ComprasPedidos.CodigoPedido)
            )
```

Columns will be resolved from the closest suitable item in scope and as that is the only table introduced in that scope level it will be tried first by default (with unmatched unqualified columns then being tried against objects from outer scopes)

But is clearer to use two part column names so readers can easily tell what table they come from and short mnemonic aliases are easier to follow than the whole table name.

Aliases have no effect on performance.